# MVC3 ViewBag Concept

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is View
ViewPage.cshtml

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Display", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div>Name:<a>@ViewBag.st</a><br /></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
<br />
}
```

My jquery for editing @ViewBag.st

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var textbox = $('<input id="Text1" type="text" size="100"  />')
        var oldText = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith(textbox);
        textbox.blur(function () {
            var newValue = $(this).val();
            $(this).replaceWith($('<a>' + newValue + '</a>'));
        });
        textbox.val(oldText);
    });


});

</script>
```

My controller methos is

```
public ActionResult Viewdetails()
    {
        User ur = new User();
        ur.Name = "Danny";

        ViewBag.st = ur.Name;
        return View();

    }
```

And my Model Class is 
User.cs

```
 public class User
{

    //public string name { get; set; }
private string m_name = string.Empty;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return m_name;
    }
    set
    {
        m_name = value;
    }
}
}
```

After editing @ViewBag.title i want to store that value and pass to next View Can anyone suggest some ideas

Comment: I'd advise passing a model down to the page rather than use viewbag.

Comment: Since i want to edit it as a label i am using this this

Comment: Pavan, I have seen another ViewBag related post by you. Please do not take it offensive. You are not using ViewBag for the appropriate purpose. Please try to find out the actual use of `ViewBag`. `Model` should be your primary medium to pass data from controller to view. Use viewbag when you need to pass some data that is not convenient to pass through model. Also, you need to learn about persistence of viewbag. Viewbag does not live forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to not use `ViewBag` at all.

So in your javascript you could give your textbox the same name as your `User` model property (`Name`):

```
var textbox = $('<input type="text" size="100" name="Name" />');
```

and then have the 2 controller actions (GET and POST):

```
public ActionResult Viewdetails()
{
    User ur = new User();
    ur.Name = "Danny";
    return View(ur);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Display(User model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

And inside `Viewdetails.cshtml`:

```
@model User
@using (Html.BeginForm("Display", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>Name: <a>@Model.Name</a><br /></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    <br />
}
```

And inside the `Display.cshtml`:

```
@model User
<div>You have selected: @Model.Name</div>
```

Comment: Isn't what's happening when you click on the link? That's what your javascript code is supposed to do. When the link is clicked it replaces this link with a textbox and allows the user to edit the text.

Comment: Not that's not possible if you used the code I have shown you: `<div>Name: <a>@Model.Name</a><br /></div>`. The contents of the link is the value of the Name property of the model.

Comment: Yeah i am able to edit Danny but not able to display edited one in Display.cshtml    I am getting only You have selected:

Comment: When do you submit the form? When a textbox is displayed or when the link is displayed? If you are submitting when the link is displayed it is normal that you are not getting the value. As I already explained you, if you want to get the value in your POST controller action you must have a corresponding input field in the form. So you might add a hidden field when reverting back to the link: `$(this).replaceWith($('<a>' + newValue + '</a>').after($('<input/>', { type: 'hidden', name: 'Name', value: newValue })));`.

Comment: You just need it to be editable on clicking? If it's just the one field you can use jquery to hide the label and replace it with a previously hidden `textBoxFor`? That way the model will change without having to go to another view, then use the submit button to "save the changes" and pass the page model back to the controller. Easiest way to do inline editing.

Comment: @Pavan, if you don't have an input field in the form you will get nothing in the controller. Try appending a hidden field next to the anchor when reverting back to it.

Comment: Thanks evryone its working except exception as Object doesn't support property or method 'createDocumentFragment'

Comment: The same code which worked in mvc3 is not working in mvc4 mainly javascript i am unable to edit @DarinDimitrov

Comment: Could you post a new question? Or undelete this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291328/ so that I can answer it?

Comment: The code is same as the above only problem is iam unale to edit remaining every thing is working@DarinDimitrov

Comment: Simply undelete your question, so that I could post an answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291328/

Comment: I posted question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292355/uable-to-use-same-code-in-mvc4-which-worked-in-mvc3 @DarinDimitrov